# Does marshmallow's backup API work for widgets?

Tags: android, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-backup-service

I didn't find anything about widget backups, so my question is, even if I assume it doesn't do that, I just want to have it sorted out:

Can marshmallow's new backup API save and restore homescreen widgets from apps? If or if not, why isn't it mentioned anywhere, is it that clear to anybody?

http://developer.android.com/training/backup/backupapi.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The backup API is for app data only.  Home Screen icons and widgets are managed by the device's launcher app, which may choose to restore them if the device is reset.

Comment: So in the end, it is possible, but depends on the launcher app playing nicely. That's good to know.

Comment: Yes, I have seen some devices where some home screen widgets and icons were restored to the home screen after reset.  Though I will say that I've not found it to be 100% accurate.